# Backgrounded processes not dying when using '&' and 'wait'

Tags: linux, bash, wait, background-process

I have a simple script which runs a few processes in the background and then `wait`s for them to complete:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

sleep 100 &
sleep 200 &

wait
```

However, when I run that script and then kill it, the 2 backgrounded processes keep running. Is there a way to wait for them complete and also kill them if the shell is killed?

Answer (score 1):

You can call `pkill` in a function that will be called on exit of parent process using `trap`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# this function will be called when main script exits
killall() {
   # echo "killing all child process of parenr pid $$"
   pkill -TERM -P $$
}
# set trap function on exit
trap killall exit

sleep 100 &
sleep 200 &

wait
```

Now when you terminate parent script by pressing `ctrl-C` or by terminating it then `killall` will be executed.